# The difference between stringvar.get() and Entry.get in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
sv = StringVar()

ent = Entry(textvariable = sv)
```

in this code is there any difference between the usage of :
sv.get()

or usage of:

```
ent.get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite less differences between these, that im aware of:

- One difference is the type of value returned, for example, if you use `StringVar()` whats inside of it will be `str`, but if you use an `IntVar()` then it will accept only integers and if not, it will return an error later on, when you try to `IntVar().get()` them. When you use `ent.get()`, You lose this advantage, of type conversion, as it will always be `str` by default, unless you type caste it later on.
- Next would be that if you say `ent = Entry(textvariable = sv).pack()`, it will return `None` and hence you cannot use `ent.get()`,else where, but instead you could use `sv.get()`. But is this recommended? No. As you cannot use several other `Entry` methods such as `insert()`, `delete()` and so on. Instead youll have to use `sv.set('Hello World')` and `sv.set('')` to insert and delete respectively.
- I dont think it is really necessary to use `StringVar()` with `Entry` widgets, unless its really important(as anyway by default its `str`), it is only really necessary with `Combobox` and other group widgets like those.
- But most importantly, remember that both(`ent.get()` and `sv.get()` will return the same output, only if you want to have restrictions based on the input entered, you can use `IntVar()` but still, its not strong validation.
- One advantage is that you can track the changes made to them, by using a tkinter variable like `BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`(decimals), `IntVar`, `StringVar`.

**To conclude:**

- The usage of it depends on the purpose of code. For a simple example like you included, its not necessary to use `StringVar`.
- I wouldnt use `StringVar` or any tkinter variable on my `Entry` widget normally, unless I want to do some specific actions with it, like `trace()` or something.

[Read more about these on effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm#:%7E:text=When%20to%20use%20the%20Variable,changes%20to%20the%20entered%20value.&text=Variables%20can%20also%20be%20used,the%20text%20in%20label%20widgets.)

Hope it cleared your doubts. Do correct me at places, if im wrong :D

Cheers

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct. The statement _" if you use an IntVar() then it will accept only integers"_ is false. The widget will still accept letters.

Comment: @BryanOakley  you might have missed the rest part of the answer where: _.."accept only integers and if not, it will return an error later on, when you try to get()_"

Comment: No, I saw the rest of the answer. The rest of the answer is correct, but the part that says the widget will only accept integers is false. It clearly will accept other characters.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you suggest a correct edit for it?

Answer (score 0):

Either method returns the value in the entry widget. The only significant difference when using `StringVar` and the `variable` option is that you have one more object that needs to be managed.

`StringVar` and the other tkinter variable classes have additional features such as being able to have a function called whenever the value changes. If you aren't using that feature, I recommend *not* associating one of the variables with your `Entry` widgets. If you don't use these features, you're adding overhead and a small bit of complexity with no extra benefit.